# when i use in hadoop 1.2.1,I want to build a new MyPatitioner from father class HashPatitioner

Tags: java, hadoop

when I use in hadoop 1.2.1 , I want to build a new class MyPatitioner from father class hashpatitioner,and it (mypatitioner) is ok . but , when I try to use it in main, eclipse find some exception.why?

```
            job.setPartitionerClass(MyPartitioner.class);
```

Tips:The method setPartitionerClass(Class) in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments (Class).

```
    public class MyPartitioner extends  HashPartitioner<Text,IntWritable>{……}
```

Comment: Could you please show me your code along with complete exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to interpret, but I suspect you are not importing packages consistently. In the hadoop API there are two MapReduce API packages `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` and `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`.

These two do not mix, and if you for instance have imported the job class as `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` and the HashPartitioner class as `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.HashPartitioner` you will an issue like it sounds like you are describing.

Make sure that the import statements in your MyPartitioner class use `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` if that is what you use for your Job setup, or vice versa. Don't mix these two packages for the same job.